# admin/content/comment/approval -> 410 Gone error (linked from content -> comments -> unapproved comments)

Tags: views, comments

I have no idea when this happened (I've been trying to fix Mollom + PostgreSQL, to the point where I tried, and removed, some core patches), but when I go to Content / Comments / Unapproved Comments (which leads to `admin/content/comment/approval`) I get a 410 Gone error.

Was this supposed to be a view? How does one recreate such core views? Is the link the result of some module long since uninstalled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a RewriteRule (written by me) attempting to get rid of the non-numeric comment error (https://drupal.org/node/1838338). I didn't count on the admin/comment/approval path

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the module

[admin_views](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views)

As well as converting core administration pages (admin/content/node, admin/people etc.. ) to use [VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), it will add a view to `admin/content/comment/approval`

Recommended.

Comment: So *perhaps* I ended up with the `admin/content/comment/approval` link because I had VBO in the past (but uninstalled it at some point)? Note, I'd be perfectly content to restore the "Unapproved Comments" link to whatever it was before VBO

Comment: Finally got around to testing. VBO doesn't fix the problem; additionally a pristine installation has the same URL working. So this answer does not work